# Specifying class template type in method declarations

Tags: c++, templates

I've searched on stack overflow and google for some time, and can't find a reference as to why the template type T is not required to be specified when referring to the template class in the class’s function declarations - see below.

Why is the template type specification not required in these declarations?

```
templates  class Foo
{
    public:
        int x;
        Foo(int z): x (z) {}

        void takeInFoo(Foo f) { // Foo<T> is unecessary.
            std::cout << "took in Foo: " << f.x << std::endl;
        }
        
        Foo returnAFoo() { // Foo<T> is unnecessary.
            return Foo(3);
        }
};
```

Comment: [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name#In_class_template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name#In_class_template, the class name is injected as if it were a public member name. For templated classes, this class name can either refer to the template name *or* a type name.

```
template<template<class, class> class>
struct A;
 
template<class T1, class T2>
struct X
{
    X<T1, T2>* p;   // OK, X is treated as a template-name
 
    using a = A<X>; // OK, X is treated as a template-name
 
    template<class U1, class U2>
    friend class X; // OK, X is treated as a template-name
 
    X* q;           // OK, X is treated as a type-name, equivalent to X<T1, T2>
}
```